# PySerial : can't write until I disconnect STLink USB cable

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded, stm32, pyserial

I'm working on some software, which involves communication between PC and embedded device over UART. I'm using STLink's USB/Serial adapter.
Most of the time communication works fine, but after some time (can be hours/minutes or even days) I got write timeout which I can't solve from software level - the only solution that works is to disconnect USB from Nucleo's st-link and then connect it again. I tried to reset or reprogramm embedded device, rerun serial script and nothing seems to work. I tried to implement exception handling which looks like this now (but doesnt work):

```
self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
try:
    self.ser.write(bytes(response))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("write timeout occured")
    while self.ser.inWaiting()>0:
        self.ser.read(1)
    self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
    self.ser.flushOutput()
    self.ser.flushInput()
    self.ser.close()
    self.ser.open()
```

serial port configuration is:

```
def createSerialConnection():
    if os.name == "nt":
        return serial.Serial('COM4', 38400, timeout=1, rtscts=0, 
        xonxoff=0,dsrdtr=0, write_timeout=1, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN)
```

so... the two devices (PC and embedded) are exchanging 5 messages every second, package size is constant (196 bytes) and before last error I've got 500k packages exchanged without any issue (I've got both higher and lower numbers before). Communication protocol is pretty simple, master(embedded) sends data and waits for response. If response isn't send back in 5seconds it retransmits last package and that's it.

I'd kill for some information on where should I look for the issue. How can I avoid it? Is it pyserial issue (then what should I use, what would be stable enough)? Maybe stlink's (from Nucleo 144) uart/usb is broken?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ST-LINK's VCOM device is not for fast orr constant communication. Buy $2 UART/USB converter.

Comment: PeterJ, thanks for input! Using RPi's UART (ttyAMA0) would work better? Or any UART/USB converter? The issue is with VCOM for sure?

Comment: Who knows... I had issues with the ST-Link, no issues with the converter. Consider the conclusion yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try with some FTDI for sure

Comment: Any will do - even $.5 chinese  ones